# Scrape page that needs to pass trough a first page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I need to do a webscraping of this page that is only accessible if the user submits something at an input and then clicks a button. If you dont do this process, the page cannot be reached by url, and will display a 404 error page.

The input is this one:

The SSL cerficate is not valid on the page so I had to disable the verification

That's what i tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import HTML
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

fst_url = "https://extranet.agricultura.gov.br/sigsif_cons/!ap_estabelec_nacional_cons" # First URL
scd_url = "https://extranet.agricultura.gov.br/sigsif_cons/!ap_estabelec_nacional_lista" # Second URL

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False # Disable SSL verification

response = session.get(fst_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    form = soup.find('form')
    if form:
        form_data = {
            'nm_razao_social': ' ', # Input that needs to be submited in the first page
        } 
        
        session.post(fst_url, data=form_data)

        scd_response = session.get(scd_url)

        if scd_response.status_code == 200:
            scd_soup = BeautifulSoup(scd_response.text, 'html.parser')
        else:
            print('Failed to retrieve the second URL. Status Code:', scd_response.status_code)
            
    else:
        print('Form not found on the first page.')
else:
    print('Access to the first URL failed.')

if 'results_soup' in locals():
    results_html = HTML(results_soup)
    results_html
```

The response is always 404

Comment: Can you priovide sample inputs? What information do you want to get from the page?

Comment: thats the input i need to submit:
<input name="nm_razao_social" value="" size="75" maxlength="100" onfocus="ConfiguraCorCampo(this);" onblur="ReConfiguraCorCampo(this)">

Comment: Yes. Can you provide concrete values you need to submit?

Comment: The value I need to submit in the input is blank actually. This page leads to a list that gets filtered by what I input, and if you just insert a space and submit you get redirected to all a list with all the items.

The scraping of the second page is not a problem actually, but i cant reach it and I need help with this part

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_url = (
    "https://extranet.agricultura.gov.br/sigsif_cons/!ap_estabelec_nacional_lista"
)

data = {
    "nr_sif": "",
    "nm_razao_social": " ",
    "nr_cnpj": "",
    "nm_sort": "nr_sif",
    "script_body": "onload=",
    "p_tipo_consulta": "",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.post(first_url, data=data, verify=False).content, "html.parser"
)

table = soup.select_one("table.LabelCampo:not(:has(.LabelCampo))")
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
CNPJ/CPF Nome Empresarial SIF Situação
01.838.723/0338-07 BRF  S. A. 1 Ativo
05.017.780/0018-44 RIO BRANCO ALIMENTOS S. A. 2 Ativo
17.589.482/0003-21 TRIPAGEL COMERCIO E REPRESENTACOES LTDA 3 Ativo
02.914.460/0274-31 SEARA ALIMENTOS LTDA 4 Ativo
02.916.265/0078-49 JBS S/A 5 Ativo
07.359.776/0003-03 BIO - TEE SUL AMERICA INDUSTRIA DE PRODUTOS QUIMICOS E OPOTERAPICOS LTDA 6 Ativo
91.302.349/0013-77 FUGA COUROS S. A. 7 Ativo
31.707.409/0004-19 COOPERATIVA DE LATICINIOS DE ALFREDO CHAVES - CLAC 8 Ativo
64.550.031/0003-60 ENTREMINAS INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO DE LATICINIOS LTDA 9 Ativo
01.838.723/0451-47 BRF S. A. 10 Ativo
07.851.247/0012-13 AGROINDUSTRIAL IRMÃOS DALLA COSTA LTDA 12 Ativo
04.431.781/0001-20 FERREIRA INTERNATIONAL LTDA 13 Ativo
01.585.358/0002-77 GVINAH INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO DE ALIMENTOS E PANIFICAÇAO LTDA 14 Ativo
02.914.460/0318-97 SEARA ALIMENTOS LTDA 15 Ativo
55.885.321/0003-74 LATICINIOS TIROLEZ LTDA 16 Ativo
```